# How to turn off flashlight when the phone rings?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg-g3

I have LG G3 with Android 4.4.2. When the phone rings or when I get a message, the flashlight will turn on.

How to turn it off?

Comment: Do you mean the camera flash comes on when the phone rings?

Answer (score 5):

This setting should be found in `Settings -> Accessibility -> Flash alerts`. It's primarily used to notify people who are hard of hearing about calls and messages.

Source: [Sprint's LG G3 User Guide](http://eguides.sprint.com/support/eguides/lgg3/index.html#lg_g3_ug/accessibility.html)